# How is the Postgres 'system database' attribute set or unset?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

One of several databases in a Postgres 10.15 cluster has been set to be a system database. The mechanism that caused this is unknown, though it may have happened at the same time that the database was converted to a template by updating the `pg_database` table.  The `pg_database` table does not have a setting to control whether or not a database is a system database, however, and I cannot find any documentation describing how to set (or unset, which is what I really want to do) the system database flag.

Comment: What do you mean by system database?

Answer (score 1):

The idea of a “system database” is foreign to PostgreSQL, it is an artifact of pgAdmin.

PostgreSQL does have the notion of a “template database”, that is a database that is intended to serve s template in `CREATE DATABASE`. You turn a database to a template database with

```
ALTER DATABASE some_db IS_TEMPLATE TRUE;
```

For such a database it is also a good idea to forbid connections, because you can only use a database as template if nobody else is connected to it:

```
ALTER DATABASE some_db ALLOW_CONNECTIONS FALSE;
```